# How do I update last row of a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+----------------------------+
| user  | date     | current |
+----------------------------+
|    1  | 20010101 |       1 |
|    1  | 20020202 |       1 |
|    1  | 20030303 |       1 |
|    2  | 20010101 |       1 |
|    2  | 20020202 |       1 |
+----------------------------+
```

I would like to update the current column such that only each user's most recent entry has a 1.

I had planned:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET current = 0 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT id
      FROM table t2
     WHERE t2.user = t1.user
       AND t2.date > t1.date )
)
```

But this tells me `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause`

Is there a way around this limitation of MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround, using `JOIN` to a derived table:

```
UPDATE tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT user, MAX(date) AS date
      FROM tableX
      GROUP BY user
    ) AS c
    ON  t.user = c.user
    AND t.date < c.date
SET 
    t.current = 0 ;
```

---

If `(user, date)` is not enough to guarantee uniqueness and there is some other `id` column that is either unique or primary key (or the `(user, date, id)` is unique, that's enough), you can do this to keep only one row per user with `current=1`:

```
UPDATE 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM tableX 
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    tableX AS t
    ON  t.user_id = d.user_id 
    AND (t.date, t.id) <>
        ( SELECT i.date, i.id
          FROM tableX AS i
          WHERE i.user_id = d.user_id
          ORDER BY i.date DESC, i.id DESC
            LIMIT 1 
        )
SET 
    t.current = 0 ;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well when there are not two records with the same MAX(date). Let's say that's valid data, and that another field is needed to determine the latest one, e.g. sort on date, ID - is there a solution for that too? (feel free to say this is a different question if not simple!)

Comment: No, if you have a Primary or Unique key in the table, that would be a small change in the code.

Answer (score 0):

or you can write it like this

```
        UPDATE t1 SET t1.[current] = 0 
        FROM [table] T1
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
              FROM [table] t2
             WHERE t2.[user] = t1.[user]
               AND t2.[date] > t1.[date] )
```

Comment: Nope, this generates the same error.

Comment: This works fine in SQL Sever.. Don't know if syntex is change in mySQL

Comment: The question is specifically about MySQL (hence title, tag), it is a known limitation of MySQL. Thanks anyway.